# iterating over files giving File not found exception even when the file is there in the dir. Can you please tell me why? Thanks

Tags: java, file-io, iteration

```
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    try
    {
        File dir = new File("D:\\WayneProject\\Logs");

        if(dir.isDirectory())
        {   
            for(File child: dir.listFiles()) //NOT WORKING AFTER 1 ITERATION
            {
                if(child.isFile())
                {
                    String currentFile = child.getName();
                    String[] fileOutput = currentFile.split("\\.");
                    processFile(currentFile,fileOutput[0]);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Please check comments. Iterating over files giving File not found exception (for the second iteration) even when the file is there in the dir. Can you please tell me why? Thanks

My other function. The fileOutput is used to set the name of the destination file:

```
public static void processFile(String fileName, String fileOutput)
{
    try 
    {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileName));
        String str = null;

        File fileDest1 = new File("D:\\" + fileOutput + "1.csv");
        BufferedWriter wr1 = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(fileDest1));

        File fileDest2 = new File("D:\\" + fileOutput + "2.csv");
        BufferedWriter wr2 = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(fileDest2));

        wr1.write("Date, Memory Free\n");
        wr2.write("Date, %Idle\n");

        while((str=br.readLine()) != null)
        {
            String[] st = str.split("\\s+");  

        if (st[0].equals("MemFree:"))
        {
            wr1.write(st[1] + ",\n");
        }

        if(isDouble(st))
        {
            wr2.write(st[6] + "," + "\n");
        }

        if(isDate(st[0]))
        {
            String subStr = str.substring(0, 20);
            wr1.write(subStr + ",");
            wr2.write(subStr + ",");
        }

    }

        br.close();
        wr1.close();
        wr2.close();
    } 
    catch (FileNotFoundException e) 
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch(IOException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: Please put some debug statements, will help you identify the issue. Also print the stacktrace. I guess the issue is not on the line that you have identified. Its probably in processFile() method.

Comment: what does processFile() function do? If you comment this line, do you still get the same problem?

Comment: Offtopic but you can use Unix path delimiter even in (Java)windows. So give "d:/WayneProject/Logs" value, my eyes it has always been more clean and easier to convert running on linux box.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect this is the problem in two ways:

```
String currentFile = child.getName();
String[] fileOutput = currentFile.split(".");
processFile(currentFile,fileOutput[0]);
```

- `getName()` only returns the *last* part of the filename - the name within the directory. So unless your `processFile` part then puts the directory part *back*, you're asking it to process a file within the current working directory.
- `split` takes a regular expression. By providing `.` as the regular expression, you're splitting on *every character*. I strongly suspect you actually want `currentFile.split("\\.")` which will actually split on a dot.

You haven't given any indication of what `processFile` is doing, but I suspect at least one of those is the root cause, and probably both.

It's worth taking a step back and looking at your diagnostics here, too. If you look at what's being passed to `processFile` you should be able to understand what's wrong - that it's not a problem with the file system, it's a problem with how you're computing the arguments to `processFile`. Being able to diagnose errors like this is a *very* important part of software development.

Answer (score 0):

Your code works fine for me. What error you might be having is in processFile function you are creating a file object from the fileName, which is not existing. Then might be trying to read the contents of the file which might be throwing you FileNotFoundException. just comment processFile function and your code will work.